# LINQ CON CASE VARIABLE PARA DATAGRID WPF

Tags: c#, linq, wpf

Tengo una consulta en sql que deseo trabajar con linq para llenar un datagrid en wpf con un data variable, para esta consulta pueden variar las horas, puede ser de 6 a 2, de 6 a 4, de 8 a 3, las horas las obtengo de una consulta a una tabla.
esta es la consulta:

```
select t.modulo,t.op,o.planta,o.cantidad,(r.perfectos+r.imperfectos) saldo,t.proceso
                ,sum(case when hora='06:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '06:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='07:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '07:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='08:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '08:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='09:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '09:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='10:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '10:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='11:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '11:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='12:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '12:00:00'
                ,sum(case when hora='13:00:00'then unidades else 0 end) as '13:00:00'
                ,sum(unidades) Total 
                from tiempos t 
                join ops o on o.id=t.op
                join ruta_confecciones r on r.op=t.op and r.proceso=t.proceso
                where  t.turno=1  and tipo_ingreso=3
                group by t.modulo,t.op,o.planta,o.cantidad,(r.perfectos+r.imperfectos),t.proceso
```

este es el resultado con las horas fijas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo de como realizo una consulta simple para llenar el datagrid

```
public partial class ingresoproductividad : Window
{
    ClaseConexionDataContext dc = new ClaseConexionDataContext();
    public ingresoproductividad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tiemposdata = (from p in dc.tiempos
                         select p);
        dgingresarunidades.ItemsSource = tiemposdata;
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: como es eso de trabajar una consulta sql con linq? estas usando entity framework

Comment: el resultado final es que esa consulta que ilustre quiero trabajarla en wpf para llenar un datagrid, con la condicion de que las horas son un dato variable, pueden tomar cualquier rango. gracias

Comment: pero no respondes lo que pregunte, usas entity framework ? o sino como accedes a la db

Comment: utilizo una clase linq para sql que me crea un archivo dbml estableciendo una conexion ado.net, asi realizo la conexion a la base de datos. gracias

Comment: linq to sql ya esta discontinuo desde hace mucho, no vayas por ese camino, se reemplazo por entity framework

Comment: como podría trabajar la consulta variable con entity framework?. gracias

Comment: pero leiste algo sobre entity framework? porque primero debes definir el mapping de las tablas, recomiendo uses Code First, https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/ porque sino conoces no tendras el modelo para armar el linq